# How to create an alert when same error occurs for more than a set limit in Error Reporting GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, error-reporting, google-cloud-error-reporting

In error reporting, how can we set an alert whenever a particular error occurrence is more than a threshold in a particular period?

For Example in the below screenshot, the occurrence of second error is more than 30 times in last 7 days. I want to setup an alert for all those error which are occurring more than say 10 times in last 1 day?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**There's no way you can set multiple thresholds for one policy and generate different alerts.**

You need to create another alerting policy that will count all the errors in the given timeframe (1 hour, day etc) and act on it accordingly.

Have a look at [some examples utilising MQL language](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-quota-metrics#mql-ap-examples) that's quite flexible and may give you some ideas.

What you need is a perfect example of a feature that you may request on [Gogle's IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187158&template=1163028) - explain in detail what you need, provide some exaples and wait for reply.